# Qt Creator not launching in OpenSUSE

Tags: opensuse, qt, qtcreator

After a few years using Ubuntu, I decided to go back to OpenSUSE.  I installed Qt Creator using the online installer from Qt, along with all the framework versions I wanted.  Qt Creator refuses to launch.  When run from command line, is gives the following error:

```
static QPlatformTheme* QKdeTheme::createKdeTheme(): Unable to determine KDE dirs
```

I managed to install Qt 5 Creator from repositories on OpenSUSE, and this one runs.  I can't tell the difference between it and the one from Qt (which I used on Ubuntu).

This version of Qt Creator gives the same error as above, but in the Application Output window every time I run an application.

Any idea what causes this?  Or how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: Once upon a time KDE and related facilities needed the environment variable KDEDIRS set. I'm not sure about Qt5 and KDE4/5, but you can check if it is set when the working version is installed, or if it works when you temporarily set it to the install prefix of KDE on your system, e. g. `KDEDIRS=/usr qtcreator`. See also https://gitlab.com/pteam/pteam-qtbase/commit/eedd300b0ecf83a365f48c084e09f1446238e157

Comment: I'll try that when I get home. Will let you know. Thanks @Murphy

Comment: I am a little tired of trying now.  Below are my settings, still doesn't work.  I'll give t another shot tomorrow.

    louis@linux-aoaw:~> echo $KDEDIRS; echo $KDEHOME

    /etc/kde4/:/etc/kde4rc:/home/louis/.kde4/

    /home/louis/.kde4/